# How many pushups are harmful for the body?

Tags: push-ups, exercise-frequency

I work on my computer at office in 45-50 minutes blocks and then take a break. During the break, I walk around and drink a glass of water and do a fixed number of pushups. Just over a year ago, I started with a fairly small number of pushups (20) during every break. For an 8 hour day, it would result in 8×20 = 160 pushups. Every week, I would add 1 or 2 pushups for every set. So for the second week, I had 8×21 = 168 pushups. This continued for the whole year and now I am on a count of 64 per set and 8×64 = 512 pushups per day. Also, in the last set, I continue without stopping and usually go to 100 pushups or more.

Before I continue this routine for decades and then experimentally find out what kinds of problems it caused, I want to know if I am doing the right thing or should I change something about it. And beyond what count will it actually start hurting my body?

Comment: This is not an opinion-based question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Edit: The assumption is that you are healthy, and have no weight issues, especially that you are not over-weight, and not too old.
- Supposing you have 10 minutes to train per "break" (not really a break any more...), the maximum amount of push-ups you will possibly be able to do (down the road) during one single break is perhaps around 400 to 800 push-ups. If your maximum is 600, your daily limit will be 600 x 8 = 4800 push-ups. If 800, it will be 6400.
- Edit: Starting at 20, if you increase your push-up counts by 45 each year, you will possibly reach 400 push-up per 10 minute in around 9 years (meaning in 8 more years).
- So your first question is whether or not, after a gradual progression, you can keep doing, let's say, 400-600 reps in 10 min x 8 sets with 50 min break 5 times per week with perhaps two days (weekend) of rest throughout much of the year without considerable harm to your body (edit: until a reasonable age (40? 45? 50? 55?)).
- (Edited) While I'm tempted to suggest other approaches... (if it's important for you to achieve a high numbers of reps of push-ups) I'd answer: you may possibly do around 100-250-400* reps in 10 minute as described above under the following conditions:

  1. That you keep following a gradual progression with fixed numbers so that the exercise remains endurance centered.
  2. That you at least avoid maxing out on consecutive days (what you seem to be doing with your last set). I'd even suggest perhaps halving the overall routine on the day subsequent to a max-out day (as in, doing only 4 sets on the next day w/ no max-out).

-> Edit: Ideally, you should not intensively workout the same muscle group on consecutive days. Depending on the load, you may even need to rest an entire week for proper recovery. But considering the fairly low load for many years, I think you could also consider adopting these two types of alternating menu: (a) one day push-ups, the next day something else; (b) one day 8 sets of push-ups, the next day only 2-4 sets if you simply love push-ups.

3. Rest a whole day (as in no push-ups) if your body says it needs a real break. -> (Edit:) I think this is the best approach to determining what is reasonable for your body. You will probably be fairly comfortable continuing this routine until your pass the 100 reps mark. Then gradually you'll see if you need to rest out a day or two or more to recover. Your body should indicate the safe maximum.

Edit: *I've picked 100-250-400 based on the information that Biswaroop Roy Chowdhury used to do about 3000-4000 push-ups a day at different intervals. If 250-400 feels too strenuous for your muscle or joints, fall back to 100-250, and consider adding more rest days.

- As to whether or not you are doing the "right thing", the question doesn't really stand as you have not set a real goal to your activity. If you just want to safely keep increasing your push-up routine during your break time, 1-2 weekly increase in reps sounds reasonable.
- And as long as you stick to the very gradually increasing rep limit and to the time limit (hypothetically 10 min), and especially with at least 2 days of weekly rest, I think you can possibly fairly safely go up to 100/10 min and maybe up to 250/10 min by following common sense rules (eat/drink/sleep well, listen to your body, don't force it when your body is tired/sick...) but you may end up needing to take alternating day off in the end, and it's hard to guess how your body will react beyond 100. I'm only guessing based on testimonies of Guinness record holders for push-ups.
- As to possible suggestions, unless you're aiming to beat the Guinness record for push-ups, I'd suggest (1) not focusing on the number of push-ups, but to vary the types of push-ups to provide greater stimulus and overall training effect.
- I'd also suggest (2) setting one day for another muscle group such as with squats. One day push-ups (w/ variations), the other day squats, perhaps even a sit-up day in the middle. Or throw in pull-ups after work, etc. You can push one muscle group more on one day, and rest it the next day. I'd simply rest the muscle more.
- All in all, setting a good, meaningful goal for yourself is the most important of all. (Unless you are trying to break the GB record, I don't think you should focus on the # of reps of push-ups, and on doing them at such high-rep on consecutive days.)

Comment: doesn't doing some many pushups overtrains pecs without compensation for the opposite muscles (back)? and negatively affect posture

Comment: Push-ups work more than your pecs. Among other muscles, it will also stimulate the erector spinae, especially if you keep good posture during push-ups. If worried about posture, you could throw in supermans, pull-ups, core exercises, and stretches... In any case, I don't think it will have grave impact on posture. Give it a try, and see.

Comment: @Luciano, doing that many push ups will cause your body to fall apart, don't do it. Sorry Didi, but there is such thing as: overtraining.

Comment: @RobSterach: I am aware of over-training. I would prefer he not "train" like that. But actually, we can't even say he is trying to train, as he didn't seem to set any goal to that effect. He just wants to hypothetically do many push-ups. At first I felt it was "insane" but then it could perhaps be done w/ not high risk considering the small increment, and when referring to people who aim to break the Guinness record of push-ups who seem to be fine with regular dose of very hi-rep of push-ups. Again, I suggested changing muscle range on subsequent day, & to rest when he felt over-trained/sick.

Comment: @Didi As I am aware you were trying to help the OP, suggesting to do 5000 of anything at the same time is usually not a good idea. Some of the people in the record book are fine because they got very luck, most of the ones that do the insane push ups challenges will damage their wrists, at the very least. There is a difference between the maximum number of push ups one can do with breaks and the maximum number of push ups one can perform safely; I believe the OP was seeking a literal number of push ups not to exceed at a given time, not the most that they could ever possibly perform.

Comment: @RobSterach: I did not suggest him to do 5000 push-ups "at the same time". It's divided in (at least) 8 sets. He would take around 9 years to reach 400 push-ups in 10 minute. A very gradual progression. His endeavor is closer to a GB record attempt than normal muscle training. As such, I referred to cases of GB record holders, who aren't necessarily all gifted, which I will add subsequently as comment. That said, I will add more nuance to my response so that it's more balanced. I'm glad you've added the other side.

Comment: (Please feel free to dispute the testimony.) 1 min push-up record breaker Biswaroop Roy Chowdhury (who was born with a heart condition) wrote in his book "Scientific Methods to Top Every Exam of Life": "Physical training everyday [sic] - I used to do as many push-ups as possible. Starting from 200 push-ups a day I went up to 4000 push-ups a day. Besides that I fixed a schedule of one hour in the morning, when I used to do about 1500-2000 push-ups (on the sixth month of the training). After that I used to do about 1500-2000 push-ups throughout the day, at different intervals."

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to spoil your dreams pal, but I would say you could, at maximum, only do a **truly** safe number of about 300 push ups, three times per week. Sorry to rat on your accepted answer, but doing 5000 push ups a day five times a week will damage you for good. Here will be some side effects of 100-200 push ups twice a week:

- Developed chest, tricep, shoulder, and forearm muscles
- Overall increase in core strength
- Stronger, healthier bones

Here will be some results of 5000 push ups a day five times per week:

- Extreme muscle soreness/tiredness
- Damaged cartilage in your wrists
- Weaker immune system leading to several colds
- Permanent nerve damage in most areas of the upper body
- Arthritis will develop too early in your hands, wrists and fingers
- Loss in muscle mass/weakened bones
- Physical deformity
- Extreme hunger/dehydration
- In rare cases, death

Now which one would you rather choose? I still would suggest working out at an actual gym however, because just like running can hurt your feet over the years if you do it often, push ups can sometimes do the same thing to your wrists. Again, I am just trying to be safe with you here, doing push ups on occasion is not that bad, usually. Good luck, pal. These are the true guaranteed effects, don't just shove them away. You will hurt yourself if you overwork.

Comment: Thanks for your input! Just to be sure that there is no misunderstanding in reading the question here, everything you wrote above is valid for 5000 pushups as you wrote, or 500 as well as in my case?

Comment: @Qasim Chaudhuri I would say 500 is still probably a little extreme; but it is definitely much safer than 5000.